# Make element width stretch to fit its children when element's parent has overflow: auto;

Tags: css, overflow

In this simplified example, I have a bookcase with books sitting on bookshelves. The bookcase is the outermost element with a defined width. The books on a bookshelf are supposed to appear left to right without wrapping. The bookshelf is supposed to stretch its width to show all the books on its shelf. All bookshelves need to be the same width, the width of the widest bookshelf.

My HTML:

```html
<div class="bookcase">
    <div class="bookshelf">
        <div class="book">
        <div class="book">
        <div class="book">
    </div>
    <div class="bookshelf">
        <div class="book">
        <div class="book">
        <div class="book">
        <div class="book">
    </div>
    <div class="bookshelf">
        <div class="book">
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```css
.bookcase {
    width: 40%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: lightgrey;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.bookshelf {
    background: lightgreen;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.book {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background: pink;
}
```

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gr9rg/3/)**

The problem with the current code is that when the bookcase width is smaller than the longest bookshelf and the bookcase makes the overflow scrollable, the bookshelf elements don’t stretch to fit all the books. Currently the shelves appear to be defining their width equal to the parent, the bookcase.

These pictures illustrate the problem. This is how the bookcase looks normally, which is fine:

[image: looks good scrolled left with narrow bookcase]
or
[image: looks good with wide bookcase]

But when you scroll right when the bookcase is narrow, the bookshelves’ green background is cut off, instead of reaching to the right side of the last red book:

[image: bookshelf background is missing when you scroll right with narrow bookcase]

How can I make the bookshelves take the full width of the overflowed element, rather than the width of the bookcase parent container?

Comment: I know we all hate tables, but this sounds like a job for a table.

Comment: The only thing I could suggest is displaying each `.bookshelf` as `table-row`: http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/gr9rg/4/

Comment: @HashemQolami `table-row` works for when there is overflow, but appears to break when the `.bookcase` is wider than the widest `.bookshelf`.

Comment: I was thinking about giving the bookshelf a width of 60vw (60% viewport with) but for some reason it's not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Javalsu, Hashem Qolami, and Danield for helping me find a suitable solution. Indeed, the trick is to utilize inherent display properties of tables. The solution I found was to wrap the `.bookcase` in another element (I'm calling this wrapper element the `.wall`). Move the `overflow: auto;` with the static `height:` and `width:` properties from the `.bookcase` to the `.wall`, and add `display: table;` and `width: 100%;` to the `.bookcase`.

The `display: table;` property is needed for when overflow is scrolling, and the `width: 100%;` is needed for when the overflow is not scrolling.

My New HTML:

```
<div class="wall">
    <div class="bookcase">
        <div class="bookshelf">
            <div class="book"></div>
            <div class="book"></div>
            <div class="book"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bookshelf">
            <div class="book"></div>
            <div class="book"></div>
            <div class="book"></div>
            <div class="book"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bookshelf">
            <div class="book"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My New CSS:

```
.wall {
    width: 60%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: lightgrey;
    overflow: auto;
}
.bookcase {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.bookshelf {
    background: lightgreen;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.book {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background: pink;
}
```

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gr9rg/8/)**

Result:
[image: looks good when scrolled]
or
[image: looks good when no scroll]

Comment: `white-space: nowrap` being key here; works great in side-scrolling off-screen photo galleries. :D

Answer (score 2):

Adding `display:table` on the .bookcase element does *almost* what you need.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gr9rg/5/)**

The only difference is that instead of the scrollbars appearing when the longest bookshelf > 60% of the viewport width, they appear when the longest bookshelf > 100% of the viewport width.

But the problem with the disappearing background is gone.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you've declared a width on .bookcase, and each bookshelf will inherit that width. If you want the bookcase and each bookshelf to always be the width of the widest row of books, set display: inline-block on .bookcase, and remove its width rule. If you need it centered, you'll need to find a way other than margin: 0 auto.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that better represents my particular use case and that doesn't declare a width on the `.bookcase` or use the `margin: 0 auto;` rule: http://jsfiddle.net/UpctC/ . Unfortunately the same problem exists. Can you please explain the purpose of the `display: inline-block;` on the `.bookcase`? I guess I don't understand what that achieves.